# Where to store Gulp modules in Laravel projects

Tags: laravel, gulp

How to manage Gulp files with the Laravel projects? I have a Laravel project with the following directory structures of assets.

```
/public/assets/
             /css
             /js
             /img
```

Where do I install Gulp modules? What is the best practices for handling gulp operations, I don't want to install Gulp on public directories as it is not safe as well as my project is hosted on Git repository.

Answer (score 2):

I usually store my JS and SCSS files in my `app/` folder (`resources/` for Laravel 5) and then I'll have gulp build them to `public/assets`.  Something like this:

```
/app/
   /assets/
     /sass/
       main.scss
     /js/
       app.js
       dependencies.js

/public
  /assets/
    main.css
    app.js
```

Comment: And the answer to "Where do I install gulp modules?" is the project root, I think.

Comment: Yeah I usually install them in my project root.

Comment: @MattM, Thanks again! Can we install node modules out of project folder? If yes how can we manage the path of required modules. Please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, do npm init to create a package.json file, then when adding node modules use the --save-dev flag for dev only packages. It will add that package and it's dependencies to your package.json folder.